QCombobox stops working after tap back navigation on android in Qt 6.4.2 C++
I have a problem with QComboBox on Android.
When I open the drop down QListView menu of the QComboBox, and I hit the back on the navigation bar, the QComboBox correctly closes, but then it does not work anymore, so it's not showing the popup menu.
Here is the code that I tried:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget w;
    QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout(&w);

    QComboBox combobox;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        combobox.addItem(QString("Item %1").arg(i));
    }
    lay->addWidget(&combobox);

    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}



Any idea for the solution? Thank you for your help!

I fail to understand why you need the MyWidget class here (not to mention the fact you use the Q_OBJECT macro without defining new properties, signals, slots nor invokable methods). The snippet would be shorter and more simple if you just made the variable w (in main) a QComboBox instead of that MyWidget thing. Can you try that and update your question (either with the shortened code or with information that your issue does not persist without MyWidget.

@Atmo If I just do that without any parent widget the application crash on android device. But I think yes the problem is still there.

@Atmo okay you are right, i updated a little bit shorter version (the problem is still there)

What is "not working anymore"? Showing the popup? Hiding it? Hiding the app? Please be more clear.

@musicamante Not showing the popup yes.

@Kaguro Then please update the question to make that more clear. Also, the attempt with NoFocus is probably based on a wrong assumption (maybe you read this, but that's for a different purpose), and shouldn't be related: if it doesn't change the result, then you can safely remove that line. It may also help to know if you are facing the problem on different test cases (emulator, different devices, etc.), eventually specifying the results, whether they're identical or not (and then how).

@musicamante okay thanks for your suggestions! I updated the question.

I fixed the question, but still no idea?:(

@Kaguro I assume that this can only be answered by users with enough Qt/Android experience, but, still, they will probably need more details about your environment (see my previous comment).
